# SystemCpuLoad/ProcessCpuLoad in GKE

Tags: java, google-kubernetes-engine, cpu-usage

1. Does SystemCpuLoad (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html#getSystemCpuLoad) in GKE define the system cpu utilization at the Pod level or the node level ?
2. Our processCpuLoad (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jre/api/management/extension/com/sun/management/OperatingSystemMXBean.html#getProcessCpuLoad) is 0.1 times the container/cpu/limit_utilization, I expected them to be close because our app i.e., jvm will be the main process running in the container